# Selecting Substring from last

Tags: substring

i have this path

```
C:\Users\sspl\Desktop\worldtaxi_14_march_2014_new\worldtaxi_12_march_2014_new\o_logo\img1.png
```

i want to select `o_logo\img1.png` from last of that string

how to do that

any help that will be appreciated.

Comment: what programming-language are you using?

Comment: Generally split target String with delimiter as array, in your case `\\`, then get the last two from the array.

Comment: Or you can use regex `[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$`. Sample code for C# - `string subPath = Regex.Match(fullPath, @"[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$").Value;`

Answer (score 0):

in c# you can do this as

```
string str = @"folder2\folder2\o_logo\img1.png";
string sub = str.Substring(str.Substring(0,str.LastIndexOf(@"\")).LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

We may use Java String class's split method to get the required output

```
public class GetFilename {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    private String instr = "C:\\Users\\sspl\\Desktop\\worldtaxi_14_march_2014_new\\worldtaxi_12_march_2014_new\\o_logo\\img1.png";
    //private String instr = "C:/Users/sspl/Desktop/worldtaxi_14_march_2014_new/worldtaxi_12_march_2014_new/o_logo/img1.png";

    private String getFileName(){
        String filename="";

            String[] splitarr = instr.split("\\\\");
            //String[] splitarr = instr.split("/");
            int splitarrlen = splitarr.length;
            filename = splitarr[splitarrlen-2]+"\\"+splitarr[splitarrlen-1];

        return filename;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        GetFilename gfn = new GetFilename();
        System.out.println(gfn.getFileName());

    }

}
```

Care must be taken while using regular expressions. String's split method takes a regular expression as input. Special characters need to be escaped with a backward slash. Also it is better to use forword slash(/) as path seperator. To understand the simplicity of using "/" instead of "\" uncomment the lines which are commented, and also comment the previous line.